# Ranorex exe not accepting parameters from command line

Tags: c#, ranorex

I have a Ranorex project* with two params which I have defined in Global Parameters and bound to modules in the test case. When I look at Global Parameters for the project, it says they are `[Unbound]` in the Module Variable column:

[image: Global Parameters view]

but in the Data Binding for the test case it shows them bound:

[image: Data binding view]

I have tried passing the parameters when trying to run the exe from the command line, as well as when running in debug mode using values entered in the Start Options from the Debug pane of the project parameters.

In either case the parameters are simply not being found by the project while running.

i am calling it from the cmd line thus:

```
$ src/main/resources/downloadAndInstall.exe /pa:downloadUrl="http://www.aone05281242.com/index.jhtml?partner=^1242^yyyyyy^YYA&sandbox=false" /pa:hostEntriesText="127.0.0.1 localhost"
```

output includes this line:

```
[2015/05/28 14:00:54.223][Info   ][Data]: Current variable values:
$hostEntriesText = ''
```

As you can see it doesn't even report the other variable that I'm passing.

I also tried it without the quotes around params but that didn't help. Also, my second parameter actually has multiple lines so I'm not sure how to ensure I pass it correctly. However, I tried it with a single line for that param to eliminate it as a source of the bug. No joy. I'm pretty frustrated. Please help...

* "Well there's your first problem, you're trying to use Ranorex"

Comment: aaargh i thought i had already experimented a lot - but more trial and error after posting this reveals it hates spaces in the parameter values, irrespective of quotation marks.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is a bug.

There are two different types of parameters

```
param|pa:<global parameter name>=<value>
Creates or overrides values for global parameters specified in the test suite.

testcaseparam|tcpa:<name or guid of test case>:<parameter name>=<value>
Creates or overrides values for testcase parameters specified in the test suite.
```

You are using the global parameters in your call, but the variables are bound to the test case parameters.

Try to use the test case parameters.

Comment: "You are using the global parameters in your call, but the variables are bound to the test case parameters." No. One sets up global parameters in the project, and then one must bind them to the test case params in order to use them.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. In my case it works also when using /pa

Comment: This is what I tried

TMP.exe /pa:MyGlobalParam="http://www.aone05281242.com/index.jhtml?partner=^1242^yyyyyy^YYA&sandbox=false" /pa:MyGlobalParam="127.0.0.1 localhost"

[2015/06/16 13:25:50.663][Info   ][Data]: Current variable values:
$MyVariable = 'http://www.aone05281242.com/index.jhtml?partner=^1242^yyyyyy^YYA&sandbox=false', $MyVariable1 = '127.0.0.1 localh
ost'